# How to manage Zend session save handler using Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework, memcached, zend-session, libmemcached

I want to save zend session in `memcache` rather than `files` bases session management. I have correctly added `memcache.dll` file in Windows 8 x64 system and check that `memcache` is working fine and have also installed `memcached` and windows services showing `memcached Server` running.

I have searched so far for managing Zend session save handler class. I found one good, may be best in my search, article by [Mike Willbanks](http://blog.digitalstruct.com/2010/10/24/zend-framework-cache-backend-libmemcached-session-cache/) and here is a [link](http://blog.digitalstruct.com/2010/10/24/zend-framework-cache-backend-libmemcached-session-cache/). Also I am pasting here that class name of Zend session save handler which is using Memcache.

```
class Zend_Session_SaveHandler_Cache implements Zend_Session_SaveHandler_Interface {
    ....
}
```

Have anybody implemented this session save handler before? If yes then please help me.

Would you please share `Zend session save handler` a class, what your using, application.ini settings and Bootstrap.php settings?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The blog post you linked to includes a full memcache session handler class. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes @TimFountain. I have tried it and spent much time on it. Only problem is it uses `memcached` class to set session values which my Windows 8 is not supporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to manage sessions for sub domains.

What I did is I placed below three lines in `.htaccess` file to manage sessions on `Memcache` rather than `files` based sessions. That means no need to make changes in `php.ini` file.

**Memcache option**

```
php_value session.cookie_domain "{your_domain}"
php_value session.save_handler "memcache"
php_value session.save_path "tcp://{host}:11211" #127.0.0.1:11211
```

By doing this no need to write separate handler for sessions management.

**Memcached option**

In `Memcached` there is slight different to specify `save_path` like below.

```
php_value session.cookie_domain "{your_domain}"
php_value session.save_handler "memcached"
php_value session.save_path "{host}:11211" #127.0.0.1:11211
```

Make sure that `Memcached` server is running.

I found little more performance while accessing session from `Memcache` or `Memcached` instead of accessing session from `files` based approach.